# How to add more than one attributes to an element dynamically in vuejs

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to think of a way to add more than one attribute dynamically.
Below is a mockup code for that.
If I loop through attributes and try to add it to **img** tag then I'll have more than one image tag and that I don't want. I want to have all the attributes inside the array to be on the same element.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
<template>
  <img />
</template>

<script>
export default {
 data(){
  attributes: [
    {class: 'main'},
    {src: '/somthing/img.jpg'}
  ]
 }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use v-bind for that purpose. Example:

```
<template>
  <img v-bind="attributes"/>
</template>

<script>
export default {
 data(){
  return {
    attributes: {
      class: 'main',
      src: '/somthing/img.jpg'
    }
  }
 }
}
</script>
```

If you would like to also dynamicly bind event's listeners you could use `v-on` same way as I did with `v-bind`

Comment: I don't want to add every attribute myself. I want to loop through it and add them all dynamically.

Comment: My method adds each attribute from an array to img tag just with one v-bind. You do not have to bind each key. Didn't you need exactly that?

Comment: But you are not looping through the attributes array ?

Comment: I modified the code in the response. Check it now. It does not require an array

Comment: So basically, v-bind loops through the object itself and adds the attributes ?

Comment: I do not how it is implemented in Vue's source code but it behaves exactly as you described.